# How to find the last words of every sentences

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I'm trying to find all the last words from my sentences by regular expression

I found this one `("\b(\w+)\W*[,]$")` but it only finds the last word of the last sentence.

These are my example sentences. I'm a beginner on RegEx can anyone help please ?

> Yasar Osman,32,usak,Kusmak
>
> Ali Sonmez,kayseri,76,Kanser
>
> Kemal Basici,istanbul,87,Kanser
>
> Soner Mentese,istanbul,32,Oksuruk

Comment: It may be easier to first `split` by newline to isolate the sentences, then regex to find the last word on each sentence iteratively

Comment: In the pattern that you tried, the comma should be present at the end and for the example strings you will have no matches. If you want to match the word after the last sentence (which by itself is a single word in the example data) use you could use `,(\w+)$` and take the value of capture group 1 See https://regex101.com/r/uFlzDf/1

Answer (score 0):

what defines a word? let's say a word consists of an arbitrary number (but min one) of characters except for space, comma or asterisk. Then your word is `[^*, ]+`. Now you want to find the last one.

The first capturing group of `([^*, ]+)[*, ]*$` is the last word of a text snippet.
`$` stands for the very end of the string. `[*, ]*` stands for an arbitrary number of non-word characters after the last word.

see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5iWOqV/1) to see how it matches your examples

or see this example of how you can use it in python:

```
import re

example = "Yasar Osman,32,usak,Kusmak"
re_match = re.search('([^*, ]+)[*, ]*$', example)
last_word = re_match.group(1)  # 'Kusmak'
```

Comment: This solution has solved my problem thanks for your help and understandable answer Raphael :)